# override and eval override in makefile; whats the difference?

Tags: makefile

what is the difference between overriding a value with/without eval command?
here are the two example codes which I would like to know the difference about

#### Example 1

```
ifeq (,$(filter $(ps),0 1))
@$(eval override ps=0)
endif
```

#### Example 2

```
ifeq (,$(filter $(ps),0 1))
override ps=0
endif
```

Comment: Hint: you must insert a blank line between comment text and code to enable source code formatting of free standing text, the 4-space indentations alone aren't enough.

Comment: There's no difference, but that '@' shouldn't be there.

Comment: thanks for replying... I did a test and printed the value of ps before and after the override and eval override flavors. in flow where I just override , echo of the ps variable before override also shows new value of variable, whereas in eval override flow, echo of variable before the  "eval override" shows old value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. When I just override, the value that I print before the override is the old value. I am using GNUMake 3.81. I am using `(info ...)` to print the value; what exactly do you mean when you say "echo"?